# Variables asincronas de js a php sin frameworks

Tags: php, javascript, async

Estoy aprendiendo php por mi cuenta, aplicandolo y mejorando proyectos que tengo ya creados en otros lenguajes. El proyecto que estoy intentando crear es un juego muy basico tipo clicker con almacenamiento de datos por registro/login y estoy teniendo muchos problemas a la hora de pasar de js a php las variables con intervalos por culpa de que php no es asincrono. Se que hay varios framworks que soportan funciones asincronas como laravel, spatie, Swoole, ReactPHP,... A ser posible prefiero evitar composer y los frameworks por el momento pero no soy capaz de encontrar ninguna manera de hacerlo. He reducido el codigo que tengo en javascript para que puedan ver que es lo que intento lograr.

Por lo que tengo entendido no es posible mostar los resultados en tiempo real como lo hace js cada vez que actualiza la funcion gracias a `$("#ammount").html(resource);` pero me conformo con aprender algun metodo para hacer que esa variable aumente asincronamente.

Muchas gracias!

```js
var rTimer;
var resource = 0;

$("#autoclick").click(function () {
  rTimer = window.setInterval (resources, 1000);
});

function resources() {
  resource += 1;
  $("#ammount").html(resource);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>XG Proyect</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f756582376.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div>
    <button id="autoclick">Click</button>
    <span id="ammount"></span>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `PHP` no es `asincrono` y toma las peticiones en orden, `javascript` por su parte su flujo natural es `sincrono` pero puede cambiar a ser `asincrono` si se lo indicas, pero la pregunta es... para que querrias hacer que `PHP` use código asíncrono?, es decir, la verdad es que eso solo te va a generar mas dolores de cabeza y problemas, si es para aprender sobre flujo asincrono deberias aprender este flujo en `javascript`y no en `PHP` ya que tratar de manejar asincronismo en `PHP` tiende a ser siniestro...

Comment: Lo otro es... porque tendrias problemas a la hora de enviar datos hacia `PHP` si se trata de un login?, quiza no estas enviando de manera adecuada la información?, quiza no estas recogiendo bien la información?, en que proceso exactamente tienes problemas?, como tratas de enviar tus datos?, porque intentas enviar tu informacion creando intervalos?

Comment: @Riven Ya sé que php no es asincrono, lo digo en el post. No sé de donde has sacado que tengo problemas a la hora de crear el registro/login, mi intención era crear un intervalo que se ejecutase cada ciertos segundos en php para incrementar una variable. Al final lo he solucionado con el tiempo, literalmente. Usando la funcion ```time()``` he calculado el tiempo que pasa entre las veces que actualizas la página y se lo he añadido a la variable. La pregunta está solucionada. Gracias.

Comment: Hiciste el recorrido y sabes usar el sitio. Las respuestas, van completas en donde dice respuestas, abajo. Si vos pones solucionado arriba, no sabemos como lo solucionaste ni que paso... Y ademas daña la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado una posible solución a mi pregunta. Usando la función `time()`, he calculado la diferencia de tiempo que pasa entre refresco de la página y se la he sumado a la variable. Es posible que no sea una solución bonita pero es la que me ha funcionado.

Por poner un ejemplo del código que he usado...

```
$conexion=new mysqli(128.0.0.1, root, "", users);  
$oldTime=mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT time FROM users WHERE user=$elusuario") ;  
$newTime=time() ;
$tiempo=$newTime - $oldTime; $recurso+=$tiempo;
```

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Yo sinceramente no se como contesta esto la pregunta. Tal vez, la pregunta este mal formulada. Pero aca mostras codigo php.. y en la pregunta no hay nada de codigo php. no se como se usa esto contra el codigo en tu pregunta...

Comment: Especifico. Si vuelves a leer mi pregunta digo que "estoy teniendo muchos problemas a la hora de pasar de **js** a **php** las variables con intervalos" no te puedo poner un ejemplo práctico de lo que espero conseguir en php porque literalemente no sabría como hacerlo, he puesto entonces el ejemplo en js y digo debajo "He reducido el codigo que tengo en javascript para que puedan ver que es lo que intento lograr." Es posible que no esté debidamente formulada, simplificando para que lo entiendas: Intento pasar un intervalo de js a php sin usar frameworks. Usé la función time para solucionarlo.